# Python: how to check that all libraries from requirements.txt file is used in framework folder

Tags: python-3.x

Python: how to check that all libraries from requirement.txt file is used in framework folder

For example:

````
python-docx==0.8.10
jsonschema==3.1.1
Locustio==0.12.2
python-owasp-zap-v2.4
pandas==0.25.3
jsonpath==0.82
XlsxWriter==1.2.6
Openpyxl==3.0.0
Genson==1.1.0
Pillow==6.1.0
xlrd==1.2.0```

How to find in framework folder that all libraries are actual and are used.

Need to have automated solution, not simple search
````

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? What do you mean by "used in framework folder"? Whether they are present, or whether some (which?) application uses them?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi for example:
possible to check that Libraries from requirement.txt file ARE INSTALLED in Interpreter

but - i have project (where i have requirements.txt file) - project - it is the main folder with sub-folders

But i need to check that all libraries from this requirements.txt file are used (not only installed) - so need to check imports in each files and check that libraries are used

maybe do we have any plugins for it?